# get <cite> tag value Onmousedown event

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML code looks like:

```
<ul>
<li class="result">
    <h3 class="title"><a class="someclass" href="url">Sometext</h3>
    <cite class="url">Cite URL-1</cite>
</li>
<li class="result">
    <h3 class="title"><a class="someclass" href="url-1">Some more text</h3>
    <cite class="url">Cite URL-2</cite>
</li>
</ul>
```

I have to get cite  value(cite URL) on click of a href.
Something like:

```
$('a[class="someclass"]').mousedown(function() {    
    console.log($('cite').text()) //if first link clicked then Cite URL-1 should get returned 
}
```

How to get cite tag value in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.someclass').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the click from reloading the page or navigating
    var cite = $(this).closest('li').find('cite');
    console.log(cite.text());
});
```

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jQuery.com/click/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jQuery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jQuery.com/find/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jQuery.com/text/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the immediate next cite element to the hyperlink(to get its text) first. Something like 
 `console.log($(this).parent().next()[0].innerHTML)`

Comment: Yes, I think the OP realises that. Could you show how to retrieve that text?

Comment: does this work to retrieve text?  `$(this).next()[0].innerHTML`

Comment: Note that the cite element is not a sibling of the anchor, because the anchor is inside the h3. (So `.next()` wouldn't work.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: yes that is true. In that case it should be `$(this).parent().next()[0].innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for jQuery's [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event.

Try this:

```
$('a[class="someclass"]').click(function() {
  var text = $(this).parents('.result').find('cite').html();
}
```

Comment: `parent()` is probably a better choice, to limit the DOM traversal to only the necessary parent.

Comment: Try `.closest()` rather than `.parents()`.